# Using a DC remote relay in low-voltage, high-current applications

Tags: transformer, relay, dc, dc-motor, wireless

I am trying to create a remote controlled miniature fog machine. My only issue is that I can't seem to find a wireless/remote relay that can work with low-voltage, high-current applications.

It is possible that a wireless relay that operates at 4 V and 10 A is not something that is widely manufactured, or is there something wrong with my underlying circuit that makes this impossible?

[image: Schematic]

I would appreciate any insight someone with more knowledge of this sort of thing could give me. Do I need to use a step-up transformer before the relay to get it up to the 12 V that most of them operate at, and then step down the voltage for the 0.4 Ω resistor to get it to 4 V? I could get a 12 V to 5 V transformer and bump the resistor to 0.5 Ω.

I also have heard that step-up transformers can burn out your motors by supplying *way* more voltage during the initial spin up, is this true?

Comment: you cannot use a transformer in a DC circuit

Comment: Wait, really? This is listed as a step-up transformer for DC: https://www.amazon.com/Valefod-Converter-3-0-30V-Step-up-Transformer/dp/B0833SQF8Z/

Comment: the website also uses the words `DC to DC converter` ... your schematic shows an AC transformer, which works only with AC

Comment: The DC to DC converter for the motor should be in parallel with the 0.4 Ohm resistor, not in series with it.

Comment: @PeterBennett So something like this? 
https://i.imgur.com/ELeBiMM.png

Comment: @jsotola What's the correct part for the schematic then?

Comment: The word "transformer" in that ad may be a translation error or other mistake by the seller.  Your new schematic is correct, except for showing a transformer instead of a DC>DC converter.

Comment: @PeterBennett I've updated the original post with the new diagram, thanks.

Comment: Low voltage DC relays have been made obsolete by MOSFETs

Comment: @bobflux Can you explain to someone who isn't super knowledgable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to switch low voltage at high current, with the switch in the positive side, these days the best option is a P channel MOSFET. Here's an [example MOSFET](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/Vishay-Semiconductors/SISS63DN-T1-GE3?qs=Cb2nCFKsA8pKpmefgRlCkg%3D%3D) that should work, and an [example schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/492093/p-channel-mosfet-as-a-load-switch).

There are power relays with 3V3 coils too, that will work, but they're pretty rare, the lowest standard coil voltage being 5V.

If you want a wireless relay that works on standard LiIon voltage, but all you have is a 12V one... I'd recommend looking at the board. Most likely the circuitry will be some RF-enhanced microcontroller running on 3V3 and there will be a 12V to 3V3 regulator. If you replace this regulator with a low-dropout one, it will run on slightly more than 3V3, perhaps lower, it depends on what voltage the chip on your wireless relay board needs. Now the relay will be 12V so it won't switch, but you could replace it with a 3V3 relay, or a MOSFET.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNxQaL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I tried to simulate a DC-DC converter that would generate 12V from the 4V on the 0.4 ohm resistive element, but could not get it to work. But the implementation of a solid state relay does work. An optocoupler could be added if isolation is needed,

There are some 2W DC-DC converters rated with 12V 167 mA output and 2.97 to 3.63 volts input. That can easily be extended to 3.6 to 4.2 volts with a series diode. They are about $20 each.

(edit) If you want to roll your own circuit, here is a fairly simple implementation that just requires a way to provide a 3 (or 5) volt logic signal to the optocoupler via remote control, which could be via Bluetooth, WiFi, or infrared. A better implementation might replace the 555 timer with a microcontroller, which could also provide duty cycle control for output voltage regulation. This circuit employs a zener and LED for rough regulation, but it probably won't work well for maximum cell voltage of 4.2V or so.

[image: SSR using opto, 555, PMOS, and NMOS boost]